# Edittext backspace long hold is not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have `Edittext` in which I have added `TextWatcher`.when I press backspace its works but if i hold backspace it's not deleting all text

```
public sTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence source, int start, int before, int count) {


    }

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        edittext.setText(s.toString());

}
```

Comment: Have u tried `edittext.setText(source.toString());` in **`afterTextChanged`**

Comment: my bad yes i am doing that only . edited qus

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
editText.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher() {
        boolean isEdiging;
        @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
        @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(isEdiging) return;
            isEdiging = true;

            String str = s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
            double s1 = 0;
            try {
                s1 = Double.parseDouble(str);
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
            ((DecimalFormat)nf2).applyPattern("###,###.###");
            s.replace(0, s.length(), nf2.format(s1));

            isEdiging = false;
        }    editText.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher() {
        boolean isEdiging;
        @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
        @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(isEdiging) return;
            isEdiging = true;

            String str = s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
            double s1 = 0;
            try {
                s1 = Double.parseDouble(str);
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
            ((DecimalFormat)nf2).applyPattern("###,###.###");
            s.replace(0, s.length(), nf2.format(s1));

            isEdiging = false;
        }
    });
    });
```